# sudo su user -c with arguments not working

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to execute command from python as another "user" with:

```
command = "sudo su user -c player --standard=1 -o 2"
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

but everything after **-c** causes troubles.
**Any idea how to execute this command with arguments for my program player?**

When I create separate 2.py script with "player --standard=1 -o 2" (in subprocess of course) and call this script from my first script via "sudo su user -c /home/user/2.py", it works ok.

Comment: try sudo -i ...

Comment: where should I add -i, please? I tried sudo -i su... or sudo su user -i... but does not work

Comment: Not strictly related to the python part of your problem, but you should consider using the `-u` option of `sudo` instead of running `su`.

Comment: Drop su and replace it with -i

Answer (score 0):

`command.split()` produces the list `['sudo', 'su', 'user', '-c', 'player', '--standard=1', '-o', '2']`, which is not what you need. `su` expects the command to run as a single argument after `-c`.

The simplest thing to do is probably to just construct the list by hand, without using `split()`:

```
command = ['sudo', 'su', 'user', '-c', 'player --standard=1 -o 2']
```

If you really want to start from a string, the `shlex` module can be helpful:

```
import shlex
command = shlex.split("sudo su user -c 'player --standard=1 -o 2'")
```