# how to use sudo su - username in python script and pass password to it

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell

I got frustrated, after searching in all available forums for this answer..
I want to use `sudo su - username` inside a python script and also I need to assign password as well to it in script itself.

```
sudo su - username
```

Please let me know if this is possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).* Also see [sudo su user -c with arguments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42344115/608639).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use subprocess in the following way:

```
sudoPassword = "your sudo password"
command      = "your command"

commandFinal = "echo " + sudoPassword + " | sudo -S " + command
        output = subprocess.Popen(commandFinal, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = (output.communicate())
        out = (out[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't be frustrated we are here to help you. Use below command in your python script:-

```
 sudo -u USER -S password
```

Suppose you are executing a second script as `sudo`:-

```
 echo $password | sudo -u USER -S ./yourscript.sh
```

In python script use like below:-

```
command = 'yourcommand'
os.system('echo %s|sudo -u %s -S %s' % (sudoPassword, user, command))
```

Also simply use like below without user

```
os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))

os.system('echo %s|sudo -S ' % (sudoPassword))
```

Comment: I tried "sudo -u testuser -S testpass"  it gives o/p as testpass command not found that too it asks for password..

Comment: @ArunTracer, can you provide me the python line where you are using this command

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

    import os,subprocess

    os.system(' sudo -u mss00d1 -S password) o/p is it asks password after I enter password it gives this sudo: password: command not found

Comment: make it like os.system("sudo -u mss00d1 -S password")

Comment: thanks, changed as you said.. os.system("sudo -u mss00d1 -S password") but still it asked for password again and says sudo: password: command not found

Comment: @ArunTracer, I have modified my answer try with all the options

Comment: @AbhijitPritam and @ArunTracer It is recommended to use `subprocess` rather than functions in the `os` module when possible. Therefore I would start trying to run `sudo` using `subprocess` instead.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam thanks for you answers.. I found one way for this... I'm able to sudo su - user1 and I'm changing as user1 and stays in user1 my script wont run other commands in user1.. Here is the python script for this.. #!/usr/bin/python
import os,subprocess


os.system("echo password | sudo -S su - mss00d1")

os.system("sudo -S su - mss00d1")

os.system("comand.sh")  
here I'm able to su mss00d1 but my command.sh wont run and I'm staying in mss00d1 home itself, here I want to run command.sh in mss00d1 user..